# Does PhoneGap support HTTP HSTS?

Tags: cordova, security

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security

> HTTP Strict Transport Security (HSTS) is a web security policy mechanism which helps to protect websites against protocol downgrade attacks and cookie hijacking. It allows web servers to declare that web browsers (or other complying user agents) should only interact with it using secure HTTPS connections,[1] and never via the insecure HTTP protocol. HSTS is an IETF standards track protocol and is specified in RFC 6797.
>
> The HSTS Policy[2] is communicated by the server to the user agent via
>   an HTTP response header field named "Strict-Transport-Security". HSTS
>   Policy specifies a period of time during which the user agent should
>   only access the server in a secure fashion.

Does anyone know if the support for this is official or unofficial or none at all ?

Comment: HSTS is irrelevant to phonegap/cordova. Whether an app implemented in phonegap would be subject to the constraints of HSTS depends on the implementation of the webview - and that's part of the phone platform.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its currently supported by all latest browsers , you can refer link for more detail : http://caniuse.com/#feat=stricttransportsecurity